# how to remove the special characters from a variable using shell

Tags: linux

```
str="#$hello,)&^this I!s> m@ani: /& "
```

I need the perfect alphabetical string without special characters. can you suggest me how to do in shell

Comment: Please explain *perfect alphabetical string*. What about just adding your expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following solution uses the [`tr` command](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tr):

```
$ str=`echo '"#$hello,)&^this I!s> m@ani: /& "'`
$ echo $str | tr -cd "[:alnum:]\"\n"
"hellothisIsmani"
```

All letters and digits, all " and new lines are allowed. If you want more or less characters to be allowed change the command.

Comment: is there any other way to remove special characters other than using echo $str | tr -cd "[:alnum:][:space]\"\n" ?

Comment: @Ramu: Why what is the problem?

Comment: thanks for rpl me. I tried with 'alnum' but it is not accept that key word that is why I am asking can you tell any other ways to remove special characters.

Comment: yes its working. Earlier I did small mistake , instead of :alnum: , I have written :alnum that is why I got error. Now it is working. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $(grep -Eo '[[:alpha:]]' <<< $str) | tr -d ' '
```

Use grep to attain only the alpha characters (removed the special characters) and then remove the space from the output.